# Connect, Insert and retrieve information from Postgresql in Javascript or JS

Tags: javascript, php, json, postgresql

I have connected and pull retrieve some data using PHP but I would like to know:

1. It is PHP or Javascrip , JS better to interacts with Postgresql
2. It is an easy way to do the same as my PHP code in Javascrip or JS? if so, how?

In my example: I'm inserting the name, last name and email and retrieving the country.

Thank you very much

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $surnameErr = $AddressErr = "";
$name = $email = $surname = $address = "";
```

```
<select name="countryselect" id="countryselect">
    <?php
    $db = pg_connect('host=localhost dbname=test user=myuser password=mypass');

    $query = "SELECT country FROM countries";

    $result = pg_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>";
        echo pg_last_error();
        exit();
    }

    printf ("<option value=Select>Select a Country</option>");
    while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {

     printf ("<option value=$myrow[country]>$myrow[country]</option>");

}

    ?>
</select>

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SAVE">
</form>

<?php

if ($nameErr == '' && $emailErr == '' && $surnameErr == '') 
{

   $db = pg_connect('host=localhost dbname=test user=myuser password=mypass');

    $firstname = pg_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $surname = pg_escape_string($_POST['surname']);
    $emailaddress = pg_escape_string($_POST['email']);


    $query = "INSERT INTO host(firstname, surname, emailaddress) VALUES('" . $firstname . "', '" . $surname . "', '" . $emailaddress . "')";


    $result = pg_query($db, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        $errormessage = pg_last_error();
        echo "Error with query: " . $errormessage;
        exit();
    }
    //printf ("These values were inserted into the database - %s %s %s", $firstname, $surname, $emailaddress);
    pg_close();

 }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JS can't talk to postgres. there's no PG drivers for JS, nor should there be. JS is a client-side language (ignoring node.js), and you do **NOT** want to allow clients direct access to your DB. Anything the JS code could do with your DB can then also be done by the person sitting in the chair. That's... scary. You have JS talk to PHP, and then have PHP talk to PG.

Comment: Cool!!!. Thank you for your answer